# tkinter molecular simulation issue

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have constructed a lattice of particles with tkinter and now I would like each particle in the lattice to move according to a list of x and y coordinates that I read into an array from two text files. I have tried to create a class with a function inside that defines movement with the canvas.move function but I get the error TclError: wrong # coordinates: expected 0 or 4, got 400. How to get around this?

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
import time
import csv


tk = Tk()
N = 100
T = 500
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=100, height=100)
tk.title("Test")
canvas.pack()
n = 5
t = 10

step1 = []
step2 = []
textFile1 = open('/Users/francislempp/Desktop/major project/C++     programs/Molecular Dynamics 2D/Molecular_Dynamics_2D-gupnvjunowwmjcfiyoursdhzytow/Build/Products/Debug/motionX', 'r')
lines = textFile1.readlines()
for line in lines:
    step1.append(line.split(" "))

textFile2 = open('/Users/francislempp/Desktop/major project/C++ programs/Molecular Dynamics 2D/Molecular_Dynamics_2D-gupnvjunowwmjcfiyoursdhzytow/Build/Products/Debug/motionY', 'r')
lines = textFile2.readlines()
for line in lines:
    step2.append(line.split(" "))


def moves(xspeed, yspeed):
    canvas.move(xspeed, yspeed)        

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.shape = canvas.create_oval((x,y,x,y), fill = color)


    def move(self):
        canvas.move(self.shape, self.x, self.y)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)
        if pos[3] >= 100 or pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = -self.y
        if pos[2] > 100 or pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = -self.x

    def delete(self):
        canvas.delete(self.shape)


balls = []


for x in range(4,100,10):
    for y in range(4,100,10):
        #canvas.create_oval((x,y,x,y), fill='red')
        Ball(x,y,"red")

tk.update()

for i in step1:
    for j in step2:
        Ball(i,j,"red")
        Ball.move()
        tk.update()




tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please show the exact error, which includes the lines of code that caused it.

Comment: We cannot run your program because essential data is in external files instead of being put in the code itself.  To show the problem, you should need little enough data to do this.  The `moves` function calls `move` without an item to move.

Comment: In your loops near the end of your code, you're calling `Ball(x,y,"red")`, but discarding the object you get back. Probably you should be saving the instances of your class somewhere (like in the `balls` list you have created). Calling `Ball.move()` (on the class, not on an instance) is almost certainly not going to work.

Comment: I suggest improving your title to something like "Wrong number of coordinates in tkinter canvas", instead of making a typo to force a title word in SO.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save items on list and use this list to move

I copy example from previous question

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- functions ---

def move():
    for point_id in points:
        x = random.randint(-1, 1)
        y = random.randint(-1, 1)
        canvas.move(point_id, x, y)

    root.after(100, move)

# --- main ---

points = []

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
canvas.pack()

for x in range(4, 100, 10):
    for y in range(4, 100, 10):
        point_id = canvas.create_oval(x, y, x, y, fill="red")
        points.append(point_id)

move()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** with your class but without data from file.

I use `random` instead of data from files to show how to create particles and move them.

Every ball moves with own speed/direction which change when touch border.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- classes ---

class Ball:

    def __init__(self, x, y, speed_x, speed_y, color):
        self.speed_x = speed_x
        self.speed_y = speed_y
        self.shape = canvas.create_oval((x, y, x, y), fill=color)

    def move(self):

        canvas.move(self.shape, self.speed_x, self.speed_y)

        pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)

        # change speed/direction when touch border
        if pos[3] >= 100 or pos[1] <= 0:
            self.speed_y = -self.speed_y
        if pos[2] > 100 or pos[0] <= 0:
            self.speed_x = -self.speed_x

    def delete(self):
        canvas.delete(self.shape)

# --- functions ---

def move():
    for ball in all_balls:
        ball.move()

    root.after(100, move)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
canvas.pack()

all_balls = []

for x in range(4, 100, 10):
    for y in range(4, 100, 10):
        offset_x = random.randint(-2, 2)
        offset_y = random.randint(-2, 2)
        all_balls.append(Ball(x, y, offset_x, offset_y, "red"))

move()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks this is very helpful, however instead of random velocity which makes the particles bounce around inside the box i would like to import the velocities from two texfiles. The texfiles are separated so that each column represents a particle and each row is a time step. would it be possible to update the particles in the lattice so that it takes the x velocity from the step1 array and the y velocity from the step2 array

Comment: yes, you can do it. You can load step1, step2 to lists ie. `moves_x` `moves_y` and then use them instead of random values `offset_x = moves_x[i]` `offset_y = moves_y[i]`. I used `random` because I don't have files - and it is only example which shows how to create and move particles. And now you can do rest.